# SimpleDialogFragment throws error from Service

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception

I have a network change listener listening for `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. That listener calls a method and shows a dialog box if there was an error. This works most of the time but I get an error when the app is in the background and this dialog box try's to show.
Here is my code

```
if(sdf != null){
    sdf.dismiss();
}
sdf = (SimpleDialogFragment) SimpleDialogFragment.createBuilder(mActivity, mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager())
    .setTitle(mActivity.getString(R.string.miscNoConnTitle))
    .setMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.miscNoConnDesc)).show();
```

The error I receive is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1354)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:127)
at eu.inmite.android.lib.dialogs.BaseDialogBuilder.show(BaseDialogBuilder.java:85)
at eu.inmite.android.lib.dialogs.SimpleDialogFragment$SimpleDialogBuilder.show(SimpleDialogFrag ment.java:1)
```

I heard that this may be a known issue so how can I get around this?

Thanks

P.S. If you didn't notice by the code I am using the [SimpleDialogFragment](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs) library